# Weird Rich Text Issue

Tags: richtext, text-formatting

So I inherited another build and the content editor is the stock Rich Text field type. The content has paragraph and strong html tags in place when you View the Source in the edit entry section, but the HTML output isn't outputting those. I personally have used WYGWAM on other builds because I like the interface better and I thought that rich text would just output everything inputed through the control panel.

My question is it possible to "remove the formatting" some place that I can check? I'm not using any plugins on this page that would remove the formatting, but I'm curious why Rich Text isn't outputting the `<p>` tags or any others for that matter on output? So I wanted to check to see if there was something I was missing regarding the Rich Text editor?

This EE site is running 2.6.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're hitting this bug perhaps... There is a patch at the bottom:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19405

Comment: Thanks Anna. Client agreed to an upgrade to 2.7.2 which should fix this too and give them some other new goodies :)

Comment: That did the trick for anyone else curious about this for future reference.